# Chrome Extension TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to add a button red highlighted place on YouTube. But it doesn't work.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "addon_menu.html",
    "default_title": "Example"
  }
}
```

content.js

```
console.log("Example is on!");


var  sttndiv = document.createElement("div");
var sttnbtn = document.createElement("button");
sttndiv.appendChild(sttnbtn);
document.getElementById("buttons").getElementsByClassName("yt-live-chat-message-input-renderer")[0].appendChild(sttndiv)[0];
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'appendChild')

[image]

Comment: If you're only meant to be targeting YT don't target `<all_urls>`.

Comment: @Andy It was not necessary at the moment. I'll do it later, thanks.

Comment: The error is very clear. The element you're try to append a child to doesn't exist. Have you done some simple debugging?

Answer (score -1):

By the error and common sense, you can see that sttndiv is undefined, this could be because there's a double space in front of it.